# tranform the origin/pivot point of multiple objects

Tags: origin

So, first off, I'm a software dev who probably shouldn't be messing with blender, so be gentle.

I've got a complex 3d model here, with about 25 discrete components (a spaceship). I've realized that I need the pivot point to be somewhere in the cockpit, so I can rotate the ship in 3d space without the camera flying out of the side of the ship. (Currently the pivot is around a point in front and below the model).

So, I tried the trick of setting only origins to transform, and then using the gizmo to move the origins. Problem is, it only works if there's a single component selected, I can't mass move the origins to where I need them (I have no idea which origin unity picks up). And moving the origin of the container object doesn't work either.

How can I set the origins for this model?

[image: origin]

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve here.
Please try to elaborate your question a bit with a more detailed description.
Maybe some screenshots displaying the problem.
Also ask yourself: do I really need to have multiple objects? (merging could be a possible solution)

Comment: 1) I'm trying to bulk transform the origin of a parent object and all its child objects. 

2) Merging doesn't seem to be an option because there are separate textures for each component, which would mean I'd have to redo the texture maps. It would also mean that any future component wise animation is kaput. 

I will add screenshots.

Comment: Select all objects, then right click -> Set Origin -> Origin to 3D Cursor (assuming that your 3D cursor is in the correct spot, which I assume it is according to your screenshot).
I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: There is no Set Origin option on right click, with all objects selected.

Comment: What version of blender are you using? Right click menus are only avaiable when you have selected 'left-click select' as your default.

Comment: 2.82, the newest. The right click menu is available, the one you're talking about isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate how to change origin for multiple objects at once as @Delagone suggested.

1. Position the 3D cursor
2. Select all the objects
3. Go *Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor*

[image]

Comment: That moved some of the origins, but some of them are red, not orange, and don't seem to move through either the 3d cursor, nor the gizmo with transforms set to origin only.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with the parent collections. Those origins seem to be fixed for some weird reason.